# log4net not logging errors and fatal in separate file

Tags: c#, log4net

I tried to separate the errors and fatal into separate log file not i dont see it logging in separate file. here is my config file. can you point what mistake i made?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\NinjaTraderLogs\NinjaLogs.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level  (%property{method}) (%property{state})   (%property{instrument}) - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
   <level value="All" />
    </appender>
       <appender name="FatalError" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\NinjaTraderLogs\NinjaLogs_Fatal.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level  (%property{method}) (%property{state})   (%property{instrument}) - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
   <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
     <levelMin value="ERROR" />
     <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
    </appender>
    <root>
     
      
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you considered logging your errors to a Database.. ?

Comment: @MethodMan, that's a different story altogether. Why? what's wrong with `log4net` BTW?

Comment: nothing with log4net.. just wondering if they ever considered using a DB. Also I went away from using Log4Net a long long time ago..

Comment: @MethodMan, Ahh!! I understand your point.

Comment: why choose db vs log4net when it has all the features of forwarders. if DB is superior, what would be the best libary to do it in c#

Comment: no library needed, you can create a log table and use same ADO.NET code to write to DB table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create one more appender ref as below under `<root>`

```
<root>           
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="FatalError" />
</root>
```

Before you call your logging in code make sure to call the `XmlConfigurator` function `Configure` (call it globally) like

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Last but not least, make sure you have write permission to the directory you are trying to create log file. I would suggest you to check windows event log once `Application` log to see if any error has happened.